# When can we say that $A^{\mathrm T} B = B^{\mathrm T} A$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, linear-regression, transpose

I was looking at the derivation of the normal equation from [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/derivation-of-the-normal-equation-for-linear-regression).

Now, the author has used the fact that $A^{\mathrm T} B = B^{\mathrm T} A$ to reach the step shown in the below image. Can anyone provide some information like, when is it true, or how we can prove it?

> $$J(\theta) = ((X\theta)^{\mathrm T} -y^{\mathrm T})(X\theta -y)$$
>   $$J(\theta) = (X\theta)^{\mathrm T} X\theta -\color{blue}{(X\theta)^{\mathrm T} y \color{black}{-} y^{\mathrm T} (X\theta)} +y^{\mathrm T} y$$
>   Note that $X\theta$ is a vector, and so is $y$. So when we multiply one by another, it doesn't matter what the order is (as long as the dimensions work out). So we can further simplify:
>   $$J(\theta) = \theta^{\mathrm T} X^{\mathrm T} X \theta -\color{blue}{2(X\theta)^{\mathrm T} y} +y^{\mathrm T} y$$

Comment: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that $(A^{\rm T} B)^{\rm T} = B^{\rm T} (A^{\rm T})^{\rm T} = B^{\rm T} A$, so if you are constraining $A^{\rm T} B = B^{\rm T} A$, that implies $(A^{\rm T} B)^{\rm T} = A^{\rm T} B$, meanining $A^{\rm T} B$ is symmetric.

Comment: Got the symmetric part...So does it mean that $(X\theta)^Ty$ will always be a symmetric matrix?...how to prove that w.r.t normal equation derivation?

Comment: Is $X$ a matrix and both $\theta$ and $y$ are column vectors? If so, then $(X\theta)^{\rm T} y$ will always be symmetric because $X\theta$ is a vector and $(X\theta)^{\rm T} y$ is a scalar (a $1\times 1$ matrix), and scalars are always symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $$C=AB$$
Then we have that
$$C_{ij}=A_{ik}B_{kj}$$
We know that 
$$(M^T)_{ab}=M_{ba}$$
So we have that:
$$(C^T)_{ij}=C_{ji}$$
$$(C^T)_{ij}=A_{jk}B_{ki}$$
$$(C^T)_{ij}=B_{ki}A_{jk}$$
$$(C^T)_{ij}=(B^T)_{ik}(A^T)_{kj}$$
And finally:
$$C^T=B^TA^T$$
$$(AB)^T=B^TA^T$$