# Prove the following matrix equation: $A'B = B'A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Let's say I have these 2 matrices:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} c \\ d \end{bmatrix} $$
and

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} e \\ f \end{bmatrix}$$

$A'B = ce + df $ and $B'A = ec + fd$

As shown above, $A'B = B'A$. But is there a matrix product property that could've told me this without having to manually check? I haven't been able to find any matrix properties that prove that $A'B = B'A$

Comment: Cf. [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753210/when-can-we-say-that-a-mathrm-t-b-b-mathrm-t-a)

Answer (score 3):

A real number can be considered a $1\times 1$ real matrix, which is trivially symmetric. Therefore if $A^TB = C\in\mathbb{R}$, then $A^TB = C = C^T = B^TA$.

Comment: It does not follow. I proved that $C=C^T$ if $C\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times 1}$. $(A^TB)^T = B^TA$ is a separate fact about matrix transposes.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the question: I thought it was asking to prove (A'B)'=B'A: I thought you were using the statement to prove the fact . My bad!